# How can I access API data (Python, Requests) in specific cells of my HTML table?

Tags: javascript, python, html, api

I've searched stackoverflow for hours and still can't find an answer so I would greatly appreciate your help! I'm building a metrics dashboard using an API and am stuck...

I'm using the requests Python HTTP library to help me retrieve sales data from an API. This is working great:

```
payload = {'data_source': 'daily'}
r = requests.get('https://api.appfigures.com/v1.1/sales/dates/2013-03-06/2013-03-14',        params=payload, auth=(api_key1, api_pass1))
data = json.loads(r.content)
```

Output in JSON (1 day example):

```
{
    "2013-03-06": {
    "downloads": 1000,
    "updates": 20,
    "net_downloads": 100,
    "revenue": "20.00",
    "date": "2013-03-06"
},....
```

I created the structure of the dashboard using HTML:

```
    <tr class="dailytarget">
        <td class="metricname">Revenue</td>
        <td>NEED TO PUT REVENUE TOTAL HERE</td>
    </tr>
```

Now, the BIG QUESTION: how do I assign the table cells to values in the JSON output? For example, I need to sum up all of the "revenue" fields in the JSON output and store them in a cell in my table. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking "how do I build an HTML table with values in a python dictionary?"

Comment: Yep, thanks for paraphrasing it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can sum up all the json data by iterating through each of your json date information

If your api call is returning an array of objects:

```
from decimal import Decimal

total_revenue = sum(Decimal(x['revenue']) for x in data)
```

this takes every revenue value, converts it from a string to a `Decimal` type and then sums up all of those values.

Now at the very base all you have to do is insert the total_revenue into your html string

```
html_str = """
<tr class="dailytarget">
    <td class="metricname">Revenue</td>
    <td>{}</td>
</tr>""".format(total_revenue)
```

all the above does is use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to put the total revenue value into a string.

The tricky part now is, how are you going to present this HTML to a user? If you want to expose it as a website, it might be easiest to use any number of python web frameworks

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I do want to expose this as a website (dashboard that can be viewed by others in my company). Do you suggest I use Django or Jinja2?

Comment: Use web.py or Flask.  Easiest way to get a Python script on the Internet :)

Comment: Thanks. Where does the "html_str..." piece go? At the top of my HTML page? Should it include any tags?

Comment: @cynthia4984, do you want to take the HTML string you generate and allow other people to view it through the web? If so, you're going to greatly benefit from choosing any of the python web frameworks, and developing your application in it. http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks.  Django is my favorite, but it is a "heavier" framework.  Additionally, I showed you a base example of how to generate a html string with `total_revenue`, but you should def look at templating engines, like jinja2, mako, or django.

Comment: Yes, I have an html page already built with the tables that I want the data to appear in. I can take a look at jinja2, I was just wondering if it was possible to insert the data into the table without one of these engines. In your example above, I thought you were providing a way for me to bypass a templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
days = json.loads(r.content)
total_revenue = 0.0
html = "<table>"
html += "<tr><th>Date</th><th>Revenue</th></tr>"
for day in days:
    day_revenue = float(day.get('revenue', 0))
    html += "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%f</td></tr>" % (day, day_revenue)
    total_revenue += day_revenue
html += '<tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;">Total Revenue: %f</td><tr>' % (total_revenue)
html += "</table>"
print html
```

Comment: In the future, you'll eventually want to learn how to load templates using a library like jinja2 or django.template

Comment: Thanks! I actually want to devote time to learning about one of these libraries. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: If you're using Django as a webframwork I'd suggest django.templates.  If you are just generating html as a standalone application, or you're using Google App Engine, I'd suggest jinja2.

Comment: If you are trying to expose this on the internet in the simplest way possible try the Google App Engine SDK with jinja2  Start with Hello World https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld then... https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates